# Consultar registos entre hoje e 10 dias no futuro para enviar por email

Tags: php, mysql, envio-de-email, sql-select

Estou a utilizar o PHPMailer para enviar um email com dados quando faltam 10 dias para terminar. Quando envio o email, estão a aparecer todos os registos quando a ideia é aparecerem os registos entre hoje e 10 dias no futuro.

**Consulta**

```
$sql = "
SELECT tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id, Nome, AlvaraValidade, AcidenteValidade, 
SeguroValidade, SocialValidade, RemuneracaoValidade, InstaladorValidade, 
MontadorValidade, MedicaValidade, ProjectistaValidade, GasValidade, RedesValidade, 
SoldadorValidade, MecanicoValidade, MaquinaValidade1, MaquinaValidade2,
MaquinaValidade3, MaquinaTopoValidade
FROM tb_detalhe_trabalhador 
inner join tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id
inner join tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id
WHERE AlvaraValidade or AcidenteValidade or SeguroValidade
or FinancasValidade or SocialValidade or GasAnexo or ClasSoldadorValidade
or MaquinaValidade1 or MaquinaValidade2 or MaquinaValidade3 or
MaquinaTopoValidade < (now()+ interval 10 day)";
```

**PHPMAILER corpo de mensagem:**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)) {

  $id = $row[0];
  (...)

  <body><p><strong>Alvara:</strong></strong>$AlvaraValidade</body>
  <body><p><strong>Seguro de Acidente de trabalho:</strong>$AcidenteValidade</body>
  <body><p><strong>Seguro de responsabilidade Civil:</strong>$SeguroValidade</body>
  <body><p><strong>Declaracao de nao divida as financas:</strong>$FinancasValidade</body>
  <body><p><strong>Declaracao de  nao divida S. Social:</strong>$SocialValidade</body>
  <body><p><strong>Declaracao de remuneracao:</strong>$RemuneracaoValidade</body>
  <body><p><strong>Credencial de instalador:</strong>$InstaladorValidade</body>;
```

**Nota:** Actualmente tenho um erro na altura de enviar email:

> Notice: Undefined offset

Aparece-me isto para as ultimas duas datas.

Comment: A tua consulta à base de dados devolve os dados como esperado? Caso não podes indicar o formato do campo das datas e a consulta que estás a realizar?

Comment: Mostra-me os dados e envia o Email. Mas não com menos ou com 10 dias para terminar a data. 
Os campos datas aparecem Ano-Mes-dia 
Já altero na pergunta e coloco o select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Recolher apenas registos entre a data actual e os próximos 10 dias

Ao utilizares o [MySQL NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, estás a trabalhar com datas formatadas da seguinte forma: `2014-03-03 11:47:30`:

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. The value is expressed in the current time zone.

Que traduzido:

> Retorna a data e a hora actual como um valor no formato 'AAAA-MM-DD HH: MM: SS' ou formato YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu, dependendo se a função é usada num contexto string ou numérico. O valor é expresso no fuso horário actual.

O que precisas é fazer uso do [MySQL CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que te permite trabalhar com datas no formato `2014-03-03`:

> Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

Que traduzido:

> Retorna a data actual como um valor no formato 'AAAA-MM-DD' ou no formato AAAAMMDD, dependendo se a função é usada em um contexto string ou numérico.

Como indicaste que tens as datas no formato "Ano-Mes-dia", assumo que o teu campo na base de dados é do tipo `date`.

Assim sendo, sugeria a alteração da tua consulta para recolher as datas da seguinte forma:

```
"...WHERE (...) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY";
          └─┬─┘         └───┬───┘     └────────────┬────────────┘
            ↓               ↓                      ↓
         campos          entre a            e a data actual
                       data actual            mais 10 dias
```

**A tua consulta ficaria assim:**

```
$sql = "
SELECT
    tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id,
    Nome,
    AlvaraValidade,
    AcidenteValidade,
    SeguroValidade,
    SocialValidade,
    RemuneracaoValidade,
    InstaladorValidade,
    MontadorValidade,
    MedicaValidade,
    ProjectistaValidade,
    GasValidade,
    RedesValidade,
    SoldadorValidade,
    MecanicoValidade,
    MaquinaValidade1,
    MaquinaValidade2,
    MaquinaValidade3,
    MaquinaTopoValidade
FROM tb_detalhe_trabalhador 
INNER JOIN tb_trabalhador on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id
INNER JOIN tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id
WHERE (AlvaraValidade or AcidenteValidade or SeguroValidade or FinancasValidade or SocialValidade or RemuneracaoValidade or InstaladorValidade or MontadorValidade or MedicaValidade or ProjectistaValidade or GasValidade or RedesValidade or SoldadorValidade or MecanicoValidade or ClasSoldadorValidade or MaquinaValidade1 or MaquinaValidade2 or MaquinaValidade3 or MaquinaTopoValidade) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY";
```

**Nota:**
Estás a fazer *match* da data num enorme número de campos, por questões de *performace* deverias dentro dos possíveis reduzir o número de campos de controlo.

Ao usares `(AlvaraValidade OR ... OR MaquinaTopoValidade)` estás a dizer que basta um desses campos estar com uma data entre hoje e hoje+10dias, qualquer um dos campos e não todos.

---

## Envio do email

> Notice: Undefined offset

Este erro indica que estás a tentar utilizar uma entra da matriz do registo que não existe.

Deverás confirmar se na selecção que vem da base de dados estão presentes os campos que estás a tentar utilizar. Para esse efeito podes fazer um `var_dump()` ou `print_r()` de uma linha da base de dados e verificar o que consta na mesma:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($validade)) {

  var_dump($row); // vai-te dar no ecrã um registo da base de dados
  print_r($row);  // alternativa ao var_dump()
  die();          // mata o script para não existir mais execução
                 
  // ...
}
```

Mediante o resultado do `var_dump` ou do `print_r` deves ajustar a tua consulta para recolher tudo o que precisas.

---

## Campos com menos de 10 dias

Para apurares se determinada data que foi recolhida tem menos de 10 dias, terás que comparar a mesma.

A maneira mais simples será converter para Unix timestamp a data contida no campo e a data actual+10dias com recurso à função [strtotime()](http://pt1.php.net/strtotime) enquanto fazendo a verificação:

```
//                         teu campo menor 
//                       que daqui a 10 dias
//                                ↑
//                                │
//        converter a data        │   converter a data de
//       do teu campo da BD       │    hoje mais 10 dias
//   ┌────────────┴────────────┐ ┌┴┐ ┌─────────┴─────────┐
if ( strtotime($row["teuCampo"])  <  strtotime("+10 days") ) {
  // fazer algo porque tem menos de 10 dias
}
```

A partir do exemplo em cima, podes realizar vários tipos de comparações para apurar se a tua data está como pretendes.

Desde que tenhas o código a executar dentro do `if(xx){ /* código aqui*/ }` já estás a criar a limitação que pretendes.

**Um exemplo de teste:**

```
<?php
$matriz = array(
    0 => array(
        "nome" => "primeiro",
        "data" => "2014-03-03"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "nome" => "segundo",
        "data" => "2014-03-04"
    ),
    2 => array(
        "nome" => "terceiro",
        "data" => "2014-03-10"
    ),
    3 => array(
        "nome" => "quarto",
        "data" => "2014-03-15"
    )
);

foreach ($matriz as $row) {
 if (strtotime($row["data"]) < strtotime("+10 days")) {
   echo '<p>O campo: '.$row["nome"].' com a data '.$row["data"].' tem menos de 10 dias.</p>';
 }
}
?>
```

**Resultado do teste:**

> O campo: primeiro com a data 2014-03-03 tem menos de 10 dias.
> O campo: segundo com a data 2014-03-04 tem menos de 10 dias.
> O campo: terceiro com a data 2014-03-10 tem menos de 10 dias.

Estão todos menos o último cuja data é daqui a mais que 10 dias.

Comment: Sim, basta um deles para enviar o email.
Uma ultima questão. Ao enviar o Email ele mostra-me todos os campos e tenho de ver qual está a faltar menos de 10 dias. Existe a possibilidade de só mostrar o que falta 10 dias?

Comment: @user3253195 Dos vários campos com datas que foram seleccionados, queres apurar quais os campos que contém uma data inferior a 10 dias, é isso?

Comment: @user3253195 Vê a última parte da resposta que adicionei agora, apresenta uma forma de poderes comparar se a data é inferior a 10 dias.

Comment: Excelente explicação. Muito Obrigado.
Só fiquei com uma duvida. Tenho de colocar esse código depois de While e antes do corpo da mensagem. Correcto?

Comment: @user3253195 Se entendi o problema correctamente, sim, após o `while(...){` fazes a verificação e vais agir consoante o resultado. Mas para o teu cenário, carece algumas alterações, tudo depende do objectivo final do controlo e da forma que queres que o email seja construído e os conteúdos presentes no mesmo. Para não alongar muito este tópico, se tiveres mais dificuldades nessa parte, coloca uma nova questão com esse problema em particular.